# Versioning Jsons with JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, versioning, semantic-versioning

I'm starting to write a JSON Schema for a category of parts that our industry uses. I have tried to look into how best to version JSON files for the future based on the schema but I couldn't find anything concrete as an implementation.

The easiest way to correlate this is to think of vehicles. We're defining a vehicles schema (vehicles-v1.0.0.json). Inside vehicles we have 4 different (at this stage) types of vehicle types - car, suv, truck, motorcycle). I think once the space industry improves, we may need to add several others (maybe say train, plane, taxi). We'd want to bump that to say version 2.0.

If the current JSON files written adhere to $id vehicles-v1.0.0, how do we ensure that the ones with train, plain & taxi are defined f or vechicles-v2.0.0?

I've had some thoughts and suggestions and examples but they all seem a bit half thought out. As far as I can tell, in our JSON file itself (say toyota-suv.json, bmw-suv.json that implements vehicles-v1.0.0.json) there's no link to the JSON Schema at all.

1. Use a `$schema` property to the top of each JSON file that references the schema in use
2. Use a `_version` object that has `{ $schema: <uri>, $version: "1.0.0" }`
3. Don't use anything in the -.json & instead let the parser deal with it.

What's the guidance on how it's been done thus far? How have you done versioning for JSON files with JSON Schema?

Also unfortunately our domain isn't as easy as Vehicles (Toyotas, BMWs, Audi's etc have small variations in specifications of the materials that they produce, so our schema has about 20 mandatory properties, and the manufacturers append others with an `x-<company>-property` field specific to their domain).